How can I adjust the modified Bessel functions for a scalar co-efficient of y'?
I have a 2nd order ODE of the form: $$ t^2y'' + 3ty' -t^2y =0$$
The modified Bessel functions $I_{\nu}$ and $K_{\nu}$ are defined as the solutions to the modified Bessel equation: $$t^2y'' + ty' - (t^2 + \nu^2)y =0$$These equations are clearly very similar. Is there a way to modify the Bessel equations to solve this equation for a scalar in front of the y' term? Or is there no simply way to solve this.

I think it should be $$t^2y'' + ty' - (t^2 + \nu^2)y =0$$

Yes thank you; corrected it

Hint: change variables to $u = t^\alpha  y$.

It does provide an answer, if you follow the hint.  For the appropriate value of $\alpha$, your equation will be equivalent to the modified Bessel equation.

Thank you for the hint! Substituting in for u, u', u'' I get the equation: $t^{2-\alpha}u'' + t^{1-\alpha}u'[3-2\alpha] + u (\alpha (4+ \alpha) -t^{2- \alpha}) = 0$. Multiplying both sides by t and substituting $\alpha = 1$ gives: $t^2u'' +tu' - (t^2 - \sqrt(5)^2)u = 0$ which is equivalent to the modified Bessel equation.

Should be a +1 instead of the $(-\sqrt{5})^2$ in the last line; made a silly mistake
